# Unable to Restart PostgreSQL after attempting to move pg_xlog to different partition

Tags: postgresql, centos-7

I am having problems getting PostgreSQL back up and running on my CentOS 7 server.

Some Context:
After noticing that I was quickly running out of storage space on the /root partition of the server, I did some quick digging around and found that the culprit was all the files in pg_xlog not being deleted. Since the /home has lots of free space, I elected to move the pg_xlog directory to a new directory on /home in order to buy enough time to solve the initial problem of the log files not being cleared. I then made the original pg_xlog a symbolic link to the new one in the /home partition on some advice I found [here](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/09/25/pgxlog-disk-space-problem-on-postgres).

But that resulted in some weird errors with SELinux not allowing Postgres to read from the new directory even after chown-ing to postgres:postgres (both the symlink and the new directory).

Since I am not all well versed in SELinux I decided to just copy the log files back to their original directory and look into physically extending the partition.

But after re-copying back all the files, PostgreSQL won't start up. The error messages don't seem to be very helpful (at least not to me). 
Journalctl -xe is reporting:

> ```
> Apr 19 00:12:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service entered failed state.
> Apr 19 00:12:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql.service failed.
> Apr 19 00:12:29 localhost.localdomain polkitd[1105]: Unregistered >Authentication Agent for unix-process:17236:1124444 (system bus name :1.588, object path /org/freedesk
> Apr 19 00:12:31 localhost.localdomain abrt-server[17258]: Email address of sender was not specified. Would you like to do so now? If not, 'user@localhost' is to be used
> Apr 19 00:12:31 localhost.localdomain abrt-server[17258]: Email address of receiver was not specified. Would you like to do so now? If not, 'root@localhost' is to be us
> Apr 19 00:12:31 localhost.localdomain abrt-server[17258]: Sending an e-mail...
> Apr 19 00:12:31 localhost.localdomain abrt-server[17258]: Sending a notification email to: root@localhost
> Apr 19 00:12:31 localhost.localdomain abrt-server[17258]: Email was sent to: root@localhost
> Apr 19 00:12:31 localhost.localdomain postfix/pickup[10305]: AA0676622C: uid=0 from=<user@localhost>
> Apr 19 00:12:31 localhost.localdomain postfix/cleanup[17283]: AA0676622C: message-id=<5ad7b4bf.TazSMT+2CbgyTlql%user@localhost>
> Apr 19 00:12:31 localhost.localdomain postfix/qmgr[1963]: AA0676622C: from=<user@localhost.localdomain>, size=45585, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
> Apr 19 00:12:31 localhost.localdomain postfix/local[17285]: AA0676622C: to=<root@localhost.localdomain>, orig_to=<root@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.05, delays=0.04/
> Apr 19 00:12:31 localhost.localdomain postfix/qmgr[1963]: AA0676622C: removed
> ```

And systemctl status postgresql says:

> ● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server    Loaded: loaded
>   (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   disabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-04-19
>   00:12:29 EAT; 1min 34s ago   Process: 17252 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctl
>   start -D ${PGDATA} -s -o -p ${PGPORT} -w -t 300 (code=exited,
>   status=1/FAILURE)   Process: 17243
>   ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited,
>   status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Apr 19 00:12:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/09/25/pgxlog-disk-space-problem-on-postgres): Starting PostgreSQL
>   database server... Apr 19 00:12:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/09/25/pgxlog-disk-space-problem-on-postgres):
>   postgresql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1 Apr
>   19 00:12:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/09/25/pgxlog-disk-space-problem-on-postgres): Failed to start
>   PostgreSQL database server. Apr 19 00:12:29 localhost.localdomain
>   systemd[1](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/09/25/pgxlog-disk-space-problem-on-postgres): Unit postgresql.service entered failed state. Apr 19
>   00:12:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/09/25/pgxlog-disk-space-problem-on-postgres): postgresql.service failed.

I must confess I am at my wits' end. Any help, even if it's just a way to generate more helpful error messages would be appreciated.

EDIT:

It appears that during the copying back of the pg_xlog files the ownership of the files changed to root. I have since re-copied those same files again with rsync in order to preserve permissions.
And now I am including PostgreSQL logs as advised in comment section below. The error message in the PostgreSQL logs is:

> ```
> WARNING:  transaction log file "00000001000000470000008D" could not be archived: too many failures
> LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
> DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: false
> LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
> DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: false
> LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
> DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: false
> WARNING:  transaction log file "00000001000000470000008D" could not be archived: too many failures
> LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-04-18 19:21:53 EAT
> PANIC:  could not open file "pg_xlog/000000010000006900000017" (log file 105, segment 23): Permission denied
> LOG:  startup process (PID 17256) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
> LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
> LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-04-18 19:21:53 EAT
> PANIC:  could not open file "pg_xlog/000000010000006900000017" (log file 105, segment 23): Permission denied
> LOG:  startup process (PID 20020) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
> LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
> LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-04-18 19:21:53 EAT
> FATAL:  the database system is starting up
> PANIC:  could not open file "pg_xlog/000000010000006900000017" (log file 105, segment 23): Permission denied
> LOG:  startup process (PID 25607) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
> LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
> LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-04-18 19:21:53 EAT
> FATAL:  the database system is starting up
> FATAL:  the database system is starting up
> LOG:  invalid magic number 0000 in log file 105, segment 23, offset 9617408
> LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
> LOG:  invalid magic number 0000 in log file 105, segment 23, offset 9601024
> LOG:  invalid secondary checkpoint record
> PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
> FATAL:  the database system is starting up
> LOG:  startup process (PID 28108) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
> LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
> LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-04-18 19:21:53 EAT
> LOG:  invalid magic number 0000 in log file 105, segment 23, offset 9617408
> LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
> LOG:  invalid magic number 0000 in log file 105, segment 23, offset 9601024
> LOG:  invalid secondary checkpoint record
> PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
> LOG:  startup process (PID 28529) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
> LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
> ```

Comment: Since you moved those files to `/home` and back, you might need to restore their security contexts. Could you add the output of `restorecon -Rv -n /var/lib/pgsql` to your question to see if there are changed contexts. If you also install `policycoreutils-python` and add the content of `audit2allow -w -a`, that would be helpful for diagnosing selinux issues as well, if you want to keep it enabled.

Comment: @jjanes I have included the tail of PostgreSQL's log.

Comment: @Kassandry you were onto something there. I copied the files back as root and it seems the ownership changed to root during the copying. I have rectified and re-edited my original post to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resorting to `pg_resetxlog` as suggested by this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8812934/539022).

I should emphasize that I only did this as a last resort, after spending hours backing up everything to an external disk. I seem to have been very lucky because
because `pg_resetxlog` worked flawlessly and the database server was up and running well again. According to comments on that SO post, using `pg_resetxlog` has the potential to make everything a lot worse.

Looking back at things, I can't help but feel that the xlog error might have been prevented if I had used `rsync` instead of plain old `cp` and `mv` to move the xlog files around.

Comment: I should also mention that I seriously considered getting professional assistance as suggested by @jjanes. This seems like a very good idea if you are more of a developer (like I am) who just happens to maintain your applications' databases and not a professional database administrator. Having 24 hour expert support in my case would probably have saved me a sleepless night.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I tried that, but Stack Exchange wouldn't let me. It said I had to wait a day before I could mark my answer as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

> LOG: invalid magic number 0000 in log file 105, segment 23, offset 9617408

That looks pretty bad.  It looks like the xlog files were somehow zeroed out when you copied them back and forth.  You may need to engage a professional services firm in PostgreSQL data recovery.  You should take a back up of all data you can still find and put it somewhere where it can't be altered or deleted.  Include both the ones on the /root partition, and whatever is left on /home, in case the problem occurred when copying from /home back to /root.

I believe the xlog file in questions would be 000000xx0000006900000017 (where the xx could be any hex digits).  It would be interesting to know if that file is all or mostly zeros.

Also, do you have the server log files from the first time you attempted to start the server?  Or, the first PANIC to have occured in the log file?

Comment: I have included more output from the PostgreSQL. The permission denied errors were before I had changed the ownership of the re-copied files back to Postgres. But I am seriously considering engaging the services of a professional. Either that or running `pg_resetxlog`.